# pass arguments to jcarousel itemLoadCallback method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

How can we pass arguments to jcarousel itemLoadCallback method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly pass arguments to the itemLoadCallback as far as I can see. itemLoadCallback executes the function you give it passing in explicitly those arguments. You'd have to modify jcarousel to send additional arguments. I'd also like to understand what you're trying to achieve as maybe there is another way to achieve what you want. You could do something like the following, which should suffice from what I assume you're trying to do:

Here is how I would do it

```
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    itemLoadCallback: function (carousel, state) {
        //get Additional Information
        //doStuff with additional info
    }
});
```

Comment: i am doing custom loading of images in slider so i need to pass the query parameters. let me give a try to this one.

Comment: You should be able to maintain a list of those query parameters outside of this function, since I'm assuming you have them in order to load the images.